# How to work with patch orgs in Einstein Analytics apps

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, isv, patch, patchorg

I think Einstein Analytics apps are incompatible with Patch orgs. Why that? To develop our software we build Einstein analytics apps and dashboards. We learned it the hard way that we cannot add those apps to the managed package. We have to use templates for that.

So to restate this. Our package that we upload DOESN'T contain the apps. But what happens if we create a patch org from that package? Will the apps be copied to the patch org or not?

An if not, how should we then deliver patch versions for our Analytics package?